# Roboteq AX2550 packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone knows where I can find the ROS packages for the AX2550 motor controller?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65519/roboteq-ax2550-packages/) by [kurochan917](https://answers.ros.org/users/5155/kurochan917/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/wjwwood/ax2550

---

Originally posted by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) with karma: 170 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1